NDSolve for a set of 3 ODEs is taking too long to solve
I am modelling solvent density in a porous medium (domain $0<x<3$ for bulk solution, domain $3<x<6$ for the porous medium) under applied pressure and constant flux, by solving a system of 3 ODEs, written as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \overline{\rho_w}}{\partial x} = f(P_h, \overline{\rho_w}, P_{eff}, x)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P_h}{\partial x} = g(P_h, \overline{\rho_w}, x)
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P_{eff}}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial P_h}{\partial x}
\end{align}
The boundary conditions are
\begin{align}
\overline{\rho_w}(0) = 1
\end{align}
\begin{align}
P_h(6) = 0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
P_{eff}(0) = 0
\end{align}
As I increase the input flux value, the numerical solution becomes more non-linear, as shown below

As the input flux increases, the solution becomes increasingly more non-linear, as observed from the steepening decrement $\overline{\rho_w}$ in the picture above. Here comes the issue. As the input flux reaches certain value, NDSolve would take too long to run, and it is almost impossible to output a solution. Theoretically, it is possible to obtain a physically meaningful solution as long as $\overline{\rho_w}$ has not reached 0. In the current settings, the code stops working as the input flux reaches $>$61.29*10^(24), although $\overline{\rho_w}$ has not reached 0.
My code:
ClearAll["Global`*"]
(*Parameters*)
stepFunc[x_] = 0.5*(Tanh[1000*x] + 1);
filterFunc[x_] = stepFunc[x - xMemL];
kB = 1.380649*10^-23;
absT = 298.15;
beta = 1/(kB*absT);
nA = 6.02214076*10^(23);
nC = 10^8*beta;
disaffty = 0.5;
dfstyBulk = 5*10^(-9);
visctyBulk = 10^(-3);
pf1 = 10^6; 
pf2 = 10^(-7); 
xL = 0;
xMemL = 3;
xMemR = 6;
xR = 9;
rhooW[p_] = 
  nA/0.0180153*(996.999 + 45.1169*10^(-3)*(10*p + 1.013) - 
     4.7193*10^(-6)*(10*p + 1.013)^2 + 
     465.8*10^(-12)*(10*p + 1.013)^3); 
rhooWLin[p_] = rhooW[0] + (rhooW[100] - rhooW[0])/100*p; 
vW[p_] = 1/rhooW[p];
vWLin[p_] = vW[0] + (vW[100] - vW[0])/100*p;
vWConst = vWLin[0];
rhooWConst = rhooWLin[0];
highLowFunc[x_] = (1000 - 1)*(1 - filterFunc[x]) + 1;
porOriVal = 0.3;
porOri2[x_] = 1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x];
flux = 62*10^(24); (*Change This to vary the results*)
waterDia = 0.3*10^(-9);
poreDiaRef = 0.3*2*10*10^(-9);
porstyRef = porOriVal;
porsty = rhoWNorm[x]/(1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x]);
poreDia = poreDiaRef/porstyRef*porsty;
dfsty = dfstyBulk*porsty^2*
   stepFunc[
    10^9*(poreDia - 2*waterDia)]*((poreDia - 2*waterDia)/poreDia)^2;
viscty = 
  visctyBulk*(1 + 36*(waterDia/poreDia) - 36*(waterDia/poreDia)^2);
permty = highLowFunc[x]*(porsty^3)/32*poreDia^2;
wStr = 1/2*nC*kB*absT*((lambda[x])^2 - 1 - 2*Log[lambda[x]]);
muStr = Simplify[
   D[wStr, lambda[
      x]] /. {lambda[x] -> (1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x])}]; 

(*Equations*)
pHydroL = pHydroPreSol[xL];
wMix = rhooWLin[pHydro[x]]*kB*
    absT*(rhoWNorm[x]*
       Log[(rhoWNorm[x]/(1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x]))] + 
      disaffty*
       rhoWNorm[x]*((1 - porOri[x])/(
        1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x]))) /. {rhoWNorm[x] -> 
     lambda[x] - 1 + porOri[x]};
muMix = Simplify[
   D[wMix, lambda[x]] /. {lambda[x] -> (1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x])}];
a = (muStr + muMix)/(1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x]);
pHydroGrad = -(((1 - porOri[x] + rhoWNorm[x])*pf2*flux)/(
    pf1*((rhooW[0] + (rhooW[100] - rhooW[0])/100*pHydro[x])*permty/
        viscty + 
       dfsty*(rhooW[100] - rhooW[0])/(pf1*100)))) /. {porOri[
      x] -> (1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x])};
denominator = 
  D[a, rhoWNorm[
     x]] /. {porOri[x] -> (1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x])};
delPorsty = 
  D[a, porOri[x]]*
    porOri'[x] /. {porOri[x] -> (1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x]), 
    porOri'[x] -> D[1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x], x]};
delPressure = 
  rhooWLin[pHydro[x]]*pf1*
    pHydroGrad*((-a + pf1*(pHydro[x] - pEff[x]))*(vW[100] - vW[0])/(
       pf1*100) - vWLin[pHydro[x]]/pf1*D[a, pHydro[x]] + 
      2*vWLin[pHydro[x]] + (vWLin[pHydro[x]]*kB*absT)/pf1*(
       vW[100] - vW[0])/100) /. {porOri[
      x] -> (1 - (1 - porOriVal)*filterFunc[x])};
rhoWNormGrad = (delPressure - delPorsty)/denominator;

(*Solving*)
{rhoWNormSol, pHydroSol, pEffSol} = 
  NDSolveValue[{rhoWNorm'[x] == rhoWNormGrad, 
    pHydro'[x] == pHydroGrad, pEff'[x] == -pHydro'[x], 
    rhoWNorm[xL] == 1, pHydro[xMemR] == 0, pEff[xL] == 0}, {rhoWNorm, 
    pHydro, pEff}, {x, xL, xMemR}, MaxStepSize -> 0.01];

(*Plotting*)
Plot[rhoWNormSol[x], {x, xL, xMemR}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, All}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Actual rhoWNorm, Plotted in Nominal X", 
 PlotLegends -> {"Normalized density"}]
Plot[{pHydroSol[x]}, {x, xL, xMemR}, PlotPoints -> 5000, 
 PlotLegends -> {"hydrostatic pressure (MPa)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Actual pHydro, Plotted in Nominal X", 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}]
Plot[{pEffSol[x]}, {x, xL, xMemR}, PlotPoints -> 5000, 
 PlotLegends -> {"effective pressure (MPa)"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Actual pEff, Plotted in Nominal X", 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}]

The error that I encountered when I input flux=62*10^(24):

